# Beautiful Soup, for loop to write data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im having trouble writing the contents of this soup function to the my ide.

I have the following soup function:

`row = soup.find_all('td', attrs = {'class': 'Table__TD'})`

here is the a subset of what it returns:

```
[<td class="Table__TD">Sat 11/9</td>,
 <td class="Table__TD"><span class="flex"><span class="pr2">vs</span><span class="pr2 TeamLink__Logo"><a class="AnchorLink v-mid" data-clubhouse-uid="s:40~l:46~t:6" href="/nba/team/_/name/dal/dallas-mavericks" title="Team - Dallas Mavericks"><img alt="DAL" class="v-mid" data-clubhouse-uid="s:40~l:46~t:6" height="20" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" title="DAL" width="20"/></a></span><span><a class="AnchorLink v-mid" data-clubhouse-uid="s:40~l:46~t:6" href="/nba/team/_/name/dal/dallas-mavericks" title="Team - Dallas Mavericks">DAL</a></span></span></td>,
 <td class="Table__TD"><a class="AnchorLink" data-game-link="true" href="http://www.espn.com/nba/game?gameId=401160772"><span class="flex tl"><span class="pr2"><div class="ResultCell tl loss-stat">L</div></span><span>138-122</span></span></a></td>,
 <td class="Table__TD">31</td>,
 <td class="Table__TD">6-12</td>,
 <td class="Table__TD">50.0</td>,
 <td class="Table__TD">4-9</td>,
 <td class="Table__TD">44.4</td>,
 <td class="Table__TD">2-2</td>,
 <td class="Table__TD">100.0</td>,
 <td class="Table__TD">4</td>,
 <td class="Table__TD">4</td>,
 <td class="Table__TD">2</td>,
 <td class="Table__TD">3</td>,
 <td class="Table__TD">2</td>,
 <td class="Table__TD">1</td>,
 <td class="Table__TD">18</td>,
 <td class="Table__TD">Fri 11/8</td>,
```

I am trying to use a for loop to write these out but my console is not returning anything.

```
for data in row[0].find_all('td'):
    print(data.get_text())
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: If First Print row ...there is something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the initial search, you don't need to re-find_all on the tag name.

Just do something like:

```
for data in row:
    print(data.get_text())
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt know this!

Comment: I ran into the same issue only a week ago! Glad this is what you were looking for!